# Substitute italic ampersand with alternative ampersand in Linux Libertine O

Tags: xetex, hyperref, fontspec, libertine, ampersand

Based in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49838/use-italic-ampersand-in-different-sizes-depending-on-environment) I want to create a command `\amper` that uses the alternative ampersand of Linux Libertine O and leaves the regular `\&` alone. The problem with the MWE below is that hyperref does not like the unicode substitution and consequently screws the title in the pdf-info up. I guess the best solution would be to substitute the regular italic ampersand of Linux Libertine with the alternative one, but I don't know how to do that.

**Edit:** I should add that the `\amper` command as defined [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49838/use-italic-ampersand-in-different-sizes-depending-on-environment) works perfectly with hyperref with fonts that have an alternative italic ampersand by default, such as Adobe Garamond Pro, Sabon etc.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{libertineotf}
\usepackage{xspace}

\usepackage{relsize}
\newcommand*\scname{sc}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\amper}{%
\ifx\f@shape\scname
{\smaller[1.2]\char"E050}%
\else
\char"E050
\fi
\xspace}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\myTitle}{Italic Ampersand \amper Linux Libertine O\xspace}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true,pdftitle={\myTitle}}

\begin{document}

\title{\myTitle}

\maketitle

Text \amper test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: hyperref is often picky about encoding indeed. I've had such problems, too, where I had to encode characters manually for chapter/section titles so they wouldn't get screwed in the PDF bookmarks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\amper}{%
  \texorpdfstring{%
    \begingroup
    \ifx\f@shape\scname
      \smaller[1.2]%
    \fi
    \char"E050
    \endgroup
    }{\&}\xspace
}
\makeatother
```

In this way `hyperref` will be able to use the normal ampersand for PDF strings.

Notice some small optimization to your macro: the test can be shorter, which is always better. Using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` is a matter of taste, but doing is usually safer.

(Your comment about using `\xspace` at the end was of course correct)

There is a limitation, however: you can't use `\amper` in section titles, unless you change the setup *not* to use boldface, as the variant ampersand doesn't exist in the bold variant (at least on my machine).

Comment: Thanks, that works but requires another `\xspace` after `\&`, i.e. `{\&\xspace}`, otherwise the whitespace in the pdf-title is missing. Could you please make a little comment with regards to what you optimized?

Answer (score 10):

It is generally a bad idea to access alternate glyphs using private use area code points, instead you should use the appropriate OpenType features, in this case the alternate ampersand can be activated with `Alternate=1` font option, now using a simplified `\amper` definition:

```
\newfontfamily\amperfont[Alternate=1]{Linux Libertine O}    
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\amper}{{\amperfont\ifx\f@shape\scname\smaller[1.2]\fi\&}\xspace}
\makeatother
```

Which, as a side effect, will solve your `hyperref` issue.

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work at all. I just get the normal ampersand in my MWE

Comment: When using `fontspec` and loading the font directly (not via the `libertineotf` package) I get the appropriate warning: `"icu-feature-not-exist-in-font" * OpenType feature 'Alternate=1' (+salt=2) not available for font`.

Comment: Okay, the solution is to use `Style=Alternate` instead of `Alternate=1`. The `fontspec` manual (p. 29, example 30) states to use `Alternate=0` with Linux Libertine, but for some reason that gives the normal ampersand as well.

Comment: Your version of Libertine fonts might be different than mine.